# Уменьшение размера изображение путем grayscale'а

Tags: java, android

Всех приветствую.

Есть такой код:

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data,Camera camera){
    try{
        YuvImage yuvimage=new YuvImage(data,ImageFormat.NV21,this.width,this.height,null);
        System.out.println("WidthandHeight"+yuvimage.getHeight()+"::"+yuvimage.getWidth());
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0,0,this.width,this.height),100,baos);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("parse","errpr");
    }
}
```

Он берет изображение с камеры и превращает его в jpg изображение.

Но вот в чем проблема:

Изображение, даже если его качество ужать до 20-ти процентов - весит около 2-х кб (2000 байтов).

Как я понимаю, вес изображения состоит из:

> ширина * длина * 3 (3 - три канала. R, G, B).

То есть, если сделать изображение черно-белым - эта формула превращается в нечто иное:

> ширина * длина * 1

То есть, тем самым, уменьшая размер изображения в 3 раза!

Я попытался сделать такое.

Но после проверки - оказалось, что изображение-то стало черно-былым, но размер как был, так и остался около 2-х кб.

Код (из RGB в grayscale):

```
public Bitmap toGrayscale(Bitmap bmpOriginal)
{
    int width, height;
    height = bmpOriginal.getHeight();
    width = bmpOriginal.getWidth();

    Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    cm.setSaturation(0);
    ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
    paint.setColorFilter(f);
    c.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, paint);
    return bmpGrayscale;
}
```

Что могло пойти не так? Можно ли уменьшить вес изображения таким способом?

Answer (score 0):

У Вас получилось что в каждом канале лежит одинаковое значение, каналов все равно 4 по 8 бит на канал, как вы указали при создании изображения `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888`, вы можете  воспользоваться другим форматом изображения, однако я не подскажу какие типы и как устроены в андроид.

вот что говорит [документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]